# Relative paths with multiple file types and collaborators

Tags: python, dataframe, visual-studio-code, path, pickle

When I want to access a pickle data file in a sibling folder, I cannot use the same (relative) paths. Because I work with multiple collaborators, this results in having to change the file_path variable (see snippets below) after each git push/pull, which is annoying, and probably unnecessary.

File structure looks like this:

```
workspace_folder
    -data
        -.raw
            -.-data.pickle
    -src
        -.data_analyis.py
        -.rapid_experimentation.ipynb
```

My collaborator wrote the following code that works on his pc in `data_analysis.py`:

```
# '..' to access sibling folder
file_path = r"../data/raw/data.pickle"

# read file
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

This gives me a file not found error, since VSCode assumes that the root folder is `workspace_folder`, and not the location of `data_analysis.py`. So I have to use:

```
# start from work_space folder, so no '..'
file_path = "data/raw/2022-03-13 conservative submissions"

# read file
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

However, when I use a Jupyter notebook, the **first** code snippet does work for me. Ergo: a .py and .ipynb file in the same `src` folder in VSCode do not use the same root folder when loading files with relative paths.

*I would like a single solution that works for both my collaborators and myself, so that we can both run the `.py` file without errors or having to change the path before and after every git push/pull.
Can somebody please explain what I'm misunderstanding?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You and your collaborators have different `cwd` sets. It looks like your collaborators have reset the `cwd`, such as add this in the settings.json file:

```
"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true,
```

So the `cwd` of your collaborators was `src` folder() while you were `workspace_folder`.